# How to i18n slugs for templates?

Tags: permalinks, slug, localization

some templates are chosen from WordPress based on slugs (e.g. `category-{slug}.php`).

Problem:
How can I use the same template for an i18n'ed slug?

Example:
I have a `category-news.php` and an english category with slug "news" and german category with slug "nachrichten". But of course "nachrichten" doesn't get `category-news.php` as a template. How can I i18n "nachrichten" so WordPress knows it means "news" before the template will be chosen internally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filter `template_include`:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'prefix_translate_template' );

function prefix_translate_template( $template )
{
    if ( 'category-' . __( 'news', 'your_textdomain' ) . '.php' === $template )
        return 'category-news.php';

    return $template;
}
```

But I think templates based on slugs are not a good idea in that case.

Comment: I didn't know the template_include filter. That seems to exactly solve my problem. Thank you very much. Any reasons why you wouldn't use slugs in this case? They seem to be very handy.

Comment: You have to create a new rule for each category now. That's not elegant and probably slow and error prone. I wouldn't do that. A term meta field with a template selector in the back-end is probably better.

Comment: You are right, especially because we use a lot of categories and a lot of languages (not just english and german). I searched for something like a "template-chooser" (like implemented in pages) before, but couldn't found something useful. I thought WordPress doesn't support something like this outside of pages?

Comment: There are workarounds for the missing term meta table on our site. :) You could also just use *one* category template and handle all the conditions in that file.